Some return TCP packets from VM are not MASQUERADEd correctly
I have a problem where some packets that pass through libvirt's default NAT network seem to skip the MASQUERADEing.
My setup is as follows:

I have some hosts that are on the
10.254.1.0/24 (Openstack) network.
On some of these hosts exists a VM that (alone) resides in the 192.11.x.x/24 network, where x is the last part of the host IP (e.g. host 3 has the IP 10.254.1.3 and its VM has the IP 192.11.3.3). This network is the default network of libvirt using virbr0.
virbr0 is in NAT mode, connected to the ens3 interface of the host.
I have routing rules on the hosts that route packets destined to 192.11.x.x to the respective host.
I have the standard MASQUERADE rules of the libvirt default network (i.e. all packets should get the hosts IP before leaving the host via ens3).

With this, I encounter the following behavior, that I cannot really understand and I don't know how to solve (lets use host 10.254.1.10 without VM and 10.254.1.3 with VM 192.11.3.3):

I can successfully telnet 10.254.1.10 from the VM. Outgoing packets are MASQUERADEd as expected and leave ens3 as 10.254.1.3.
I CANNOT telnet 192.11.3.3: tcpdump on ens3 of 10.254.1.3 shows the incoming packets but outgoing packets are not MASQUERADEd and try to leave as 192.11.3.3 with the correct destination but do not reach 10.254.1.10

If that might be important: the VM should later serve as a K8s node using Flannel CNI, the host without a VM serves as the control-plane.
I expect to be able to telnet 192.11.3.3 from 10.254.1.10 and get a response back. I searched online for solutions but could not find something that suits my problem.
The last answer here Is it possible to masquerade a packet on a bridge? suggests that bridged packets might not be MASQUERADEd - but then why does it work when the call is initiated by the VM and does not when it is initiated by an outside host?
Thanks for any help, I am quite new to networking and it already gave me some long nights without the sweet feeling of success ;)
Also I would be grateful for any other solutions regarding how to setup K8s with nodes that are not directly connected in a shared network but reside on hosts (that share the same network).


I CANNOT telnet 192.11.3.3: tcpdump on ens3 of 10.254.1.3 shows the incoming packages but outgoing packages are not MASQUERADEd and try to leave as 192.11.3.3 with the correct destination but do not reach 10.254.1.10

This seems completely normal to me. You contacted 192.11.3.3, so your OS will be expecting to get a reply from 192.11.3.3, not from 10.254.1.3. Masquerading the reply packets so that they appear as if coming from 10.254.1.3 – even though the initial contact was not to this address – really wouldn't help with establishing a connection; neither the client's own firewall nor their TCP stack would accept such a packet.
If you're not getting a response from 192.11.3.3, the problem is not in the lack of NAT but rather something to do with the firewall filter rules, most likely.
Generally speaking, DNAT and SNAT/MASQUERADE is decided at connection or flow level, not at individual packet level – i.e. the decision is made for the first packet and then automatically applied to all subsequent packets in the same flow, both forwards and backwards. So if the initial inbound packet was or wasn't DNATed, then the outbound responses accordingly will or won't be SNATed to match. (In other words, the NAT is stateful.)
(So if you really want the host to respond as 10.254.1.3 then you must start with telnet 10.254.1.3 and have that host DNAT this to 192.11.3.3.)

The last answer here Is it possible to masquerade a packet on a bridge? suggests that bridged packets might not be MASQUERADEd

That thread is about packets that are exclusively only bridged from A to B. It doesn't apply here, because the packets aren't only bridged but also routed from one host interface to another – with NAT being applied as part of routing.
